# Mac OS X, application's developer name?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I have created an app for mac os x using xcode 4

In the build settings I see my name (the mac os x registered user's name)

Anyhow, I want to share the app but I don't want other to know that I created this app

So, is there a way to find out who created the app ?

If there's is how can I remove my name from the app ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same concern - making a Mac app not intended for the app store. I want to code sign it, but I don't want my name to be retrievable from the app, since I'm the one who developed it.

Answer (score 0):

It has some smell, to distribute an application anonymously. Anyway: You can change the information of your application by editing the *Info.plist* file inside your .app-bundle.

Right-click your application and select "Show package contents" from the context-menu. Open the folders and search for the "Info.plist" file. Open the file with TextWrangler, BBEdit oder the PropertyFile-Editor of XCode and search for your name. You can then simply replace it with anything else.

**But remember**:

An application should never ever been distributed without informations on the developer. The described method will only remove all "visible" informations on you. Informations on you that are part of the compiled binary won't be changed by this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. how can I distribute the app completely anonymously or with a nick name but without my real name ?

Comment: @Andy: sorry, the fact trying to distribute your application completely anonymously tells me, that you should not distribute your software, since you'll get in conflict with the authorities.

Comment: hhh, no, my application is completely legal, I made it for someone who paid me to create it, and I don't want him to know my name; thanks anyway :)

Comment: An application you have written, where you have been paid for anonymously and a software, that should be distributed anonymously - shall I call McAffee, Kaspersky, Norton and Apple immediately or do you want to think about what you're doing?

Comment: hhh, you're making it a big deal, It's a simple app only 350 kb in size, It notify the user using growl if there's a new mail in his yahoo mail, and when clicking the growl alert opens the browser on yahoo.com, that's it :D (well tha app is only 20 kb the growl framework is 330kb)

Comment: @Andy: After changing what's in the Info.plist, if you want to find out if there's any other reference to your name, just use grep -r (and maybe find -exec iconv|grep, for UTF-16 or -32). If you can't find your name, neither can your "client". Unless, of course, he can track you through the payment or other communication, in which case he can still send his associates to break your kneecaps or turn you over to the FBI in his stead or whatever you're afraid of…